# “Kurs” and “Bestand” in a financial context

Tags: meaning, technical-terminology

I've created a stock account and invested a small amount of money.
under the status of the account, two amount of euros stand out:

1. Bestand
2. Kurs

The Kurs amount is slightly higher than Bestand .
What is their difference? Should I provide more info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, "Bestand" is the amount of money I have invested in this so far, and "Kurs" is the current balance.

Comment: With "the amount of money I have invested" you mean the value at which you bought the stocks, right?

Comment: yesssssssssssss

Answer (score 1):

*Bestand* should normally be the **number** of shares you own.

*Kurs* should be the **value** of one share.

Are you sure "Bestand" is in €? That would be highly uncommon.

[Here](https://www.bvi.de/kapitalanlage/privatanleger/privatanleger/news/den-depotauszug-richtig-verstehen/?tx_news_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=News&tx_news_pi1%5Baction%5D=detail&cHash=e93467ad7020963ece3b2a6954f0577e) is a link that should explain it.

Comment: I think what you are referring to, is equivalent to what is called " Bestand in Stück" over there.